# Make a div with three inner floated divs responsive for mobile

Tags: html, css

I have an outer header div that contains three floated divs within it.

The **inner leftHeader** and **inner rightHeader** are both **empty**.  Only the middleHeader contains a few links.

When viewed on mobile (320 - 420), I only want the middleHeader to be visible and to take up all available space - I have code for this given below?

What is happening is middleHeader is responsive but only seems to take up a third of the row even though I have width 100%, I want middleHeader to take up full 100% of the space in its row.  Any help would be great. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

**The HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="leftHeader">Empty</div>

    <div class="middleHeader"><nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="page1.html" title="">Link to page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page2.html" title="">Link to page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page3.html" title="">Link to page 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                </nav></div>

    <div class="rightHeader">Empty</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS for Mobile**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 420px) and (orientation : portrait){

    div.leftHeader{visibility:hidden;}

    div.middleHeader{width: 100%; float: none; text-align:left;}

    div.rightHeader{visibility:hidden;}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Visibility: hidden;` does not prevent the element from occupying space inside box-model of that element.

You need to use `display:none;` - this hides the content as well as doesn't allows the element to occupy any browser space.

---

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 420px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .middleHeader {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
    background: red;
    /* for demo purpose */
  }
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="leftHeader hidden-xs">Empty</div>

  <div class="middleHeader">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.html" title="">Link to page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page2.html" title="">Link to page 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page3.html" title="">Link to page 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="rightHeader hidden-xs">Empty</div>
</div>
```

Try viewing the code snippet example and resize your browser from 320 to 480px, you'll see the extra content hiding.

Answer (score 5):

```
visibility:hidden;
```

only makes the div not visible, but left empty space where hidden div should be

try instead:

```
display: none;
```

Comment: Thanks, Milan.  Okay, that works to a point.  But the middleHeader div is now off to the left side with a gap on the right.  I tried setting the margin: 0 auto; to align it to the middle of the page, but nothing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hard to say just with CSS code you provided.

As @Iwozniak said, Bootstrap is good and powerful solution for responsive sites. If you want something less "huge", my other favorite framework is Materialize (materializecss.com). In both frameworks are many helper classes for situations like this.

Comment: Thanks Milan, shall check out the Materialize framework when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use Bootstrap?

```
<div class="header row">

  <div class="leftHeader hidden-xs col-sm-3">Empty</div>

  <div class="middleHeader col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><nav>

  <div class="rightHeader hidden-xs col-sm-3">Empty</div>

</div>
```

hidden-xs class hide both divs and col-xs-12 will force middleHeader to 100% width.

Comment: Thanks Iwozniak for the suggestion, looks easy enough.  I have never used Bootstrap though.   I think I may have to look into using it.

Comment: Bootstrap makes RWD really easy!

Answer (score 1):

I just created what you are ideally asking for, entirely from scratch using HTML5 and CSS, plus I have created a Public Domain GitHub directory for this, where you can freely use the code at https://github.com/danielrutter/Header-Script---1-Row-3-Columns

This is the code exactly as it was developed on 18th August 2016 from the first submission through GitHub:

index.html or index.php (depending on your preference [currently set to .html]):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Header Script - 1 Row, 3 Columns</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<header>
<header-left>LEFT</header-left>
<header-center>OBJECT PLACEMENT</header-center>
<header-right>RIGHT</header-right>
</header>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css/styles.css:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

header-left {
  width: 18%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

header-center {
  width: 64%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline;
}

header-right {
  width: 18%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Really cool, thanks Daniel, trying it out now and seems to be working great. Thanks again, Andy ;-)

Comment: That is great to hear @AndyR :)! This is actually my 1st ever StackOverflow & GitHub script published to the public domain. If you need help with other scripts and so forth, make sure to contact me through danielrutter.com. I am coding for free right now when I have the time, as I am training to be a Full Stack Developer, as long as its within my field of expertise.